# Retrieve column and row elements based on single element

Tags: matlab

Given a m x n matrix, how can I obtain the ordered (top-left to bottom-right) entries from the column and row corresponding to a given index without the indexed element itself?

For example, given the 5 x 5 magic square matrix A I'd like to retrieve the column and row elements corresponding to the (4,2) element:

```
A =
    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9
```

This should yield:

```
B =
    24     5     6    10    19    21     3    18
```

alternatively, requesting the (5,5) element would yield:

```
B =
    15    16    22     3    11    18    25     2
```

or, for (3,2) we'd have:

```
B =
    24     5     4    13    20    22    12     18
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the order of elements in output `B` isn't important you can use this -

```
B = setdiff([A(:,col_id).' A(row_id,:)],A(row_id,col_id),'stable')
```

If the order is important, this messy solution looks fit -

```
B = [A(1:row_id-1,col_id).' A(row_id,1:col_id-1) ...
                                    A(row_id,col_id+1:end) A(row_id+1:end,col_id).']
```

Comment: unfortunately, the order is important: it should be top-left to bottom right, going right first. I'll update the question

Comment: @WouterKuijsters Check out the added code at the end?